# redirect all local requests for a domain name to local server

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, self-hosting

I host a small asp.net website for my business on a Windows Server 2019 box. I use IIS to host it and access it from both outside my local network (from home) and from within the network. I use a domain name that I own to access the site both internally and externally. I use a mix of devices internally to access the site from desktops, phones, and chromebooks.

Recently, something unknown changed and I can no longer access the site from my internal network by its domain name. The site times out on the local network by it's domain name. I can still access the site normally from outside my network by it's domain name.

I use a Comcast Business modem/router for my LAN. At this time, I would prefer to stay with this device if possible, but I have in the past used a DD-WRT router on my network but the device I use is no longer getting updates for DD-WRT. I had made no adjustments to allow for the domain name to be routed locally on the router, it seemed to manage that on its own without a redirect loop.

I contacted Comcast about any potential changes to the firmware of the device and they were of no help.

I have in the short term set up host files to redirect the domain name to the server’s local IP but that fix only works on the desktops and I would like to find a blanket solution. I would prefer to find a way to do this at the router, but could potentially host a DNS service on the server but I have not gotten that to work yet.

Previously, I used a DDWRT router with what I remember being netmasq to redirect the url to the server IP but would like to not have to do that if possible.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your question to include the details of what you are doing when the problem occurs and the error you are encountering. Have you made changes to the server recently? What happens when you use the host file? Are you trying to connect from a local network or external network? What devices are you attempting to connect with? Have you replaced the modem/router recently? What domain name and DNS solution are you using currently? Any additional information could be helpful.

Comment: I've done my best to clarify the mess of a question I asked.

Comment: (1) I don’t understand why your question title says “redirect”. You want to be able to access your server by its domain name from all clients, including those that are near the server (i.e., “local”). AFAICT, you don’t *want* to redirect anything. Please [don’t ask how to fix your failed attempt at a solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/195817 "What is the XY problem?"); ask how to solve your actual problem. (2) What happens when you ping your server from a local client? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Do you know how to use tools like ``dig`` and ``nslookup``?  (4) Are you connected to the Internet with NAT?  (5) I agree that you may need to run your own DNS server.  It doesn’t need to be on the router or the ASP.NET server; it can be on any computer.

Comment: 1) I may misuse some terminology here. If I were particularly adept with these concepts I likely wouldn't be seeking help. I used the term 'redirect' because I presume what I want is for the router to know to send the request for the domain name to the server, rather than out to the internet. 2) ping from a local machine to the server's IP works just fine. 3) I am not aware of dig but nslookup shows the domain name's address as my external IP.